# How to get a value of object in an array of object and string in TS?

Tags: typescript, types, typeerror

Let's say I have this array

```
const testData = [
  { properties: { number: 1, name: 'haha' } , second: 'this type'},
  ['one', 'two', 'three'],
];
```

I want to get the value of 'second' which is 'this type' like this:

```
const wantToGet = testData[0].second;
```

But the typescript generates an error saying

```
Property 'second' does not exist on type 'string[] | { properties: { number: number; name: string; }; second: string; }'.
Property 'second' does not exist on type 'string[]'
```

testData[0] is always an object, not an array. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`testData` is inferred as `({ ... } | string[])[]`, just like how

```
const thing = [1, "2", 3, "4"];
```

is inferred as `(number | string)[]`. If you want it to be inferred as a tuple, you can use a [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions),

```
const testData = [
  { properties: { number: 1, name: 'haha' } , second: 'this type'},
  ['one', 'two', 'three'],
] as const;
```

but this makes `testData` immutable (even the object and array inside are immutable). If you want to be able to mutate it, you should give it an explicit type annotation:

```
const testData: [{ properties: { ... } ... }, string[]] = [
  { properties: { number: 1, name: 'haha' } , second: 'this type'},
  ['one', 'two', 'three'],
];
```

Or you can use a helper function to infer it as a tuple:

```
function tuple<T extends readonly unknown[]>(args: [...T]) { return args }

const testData = tuple([
  { properties: { number: 1, name: 'haha' } , second: 'this type'},
  ['one', 'two', 'three'],
]);
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Nnb9vN)

Comment: I don't need to change the data this time, so 'as const' will work. But thank you for the other ways!

Answer (score 2):

What typescript knows is that `testData` is a list of either an array of strings or an object of shape `{properties: {number: number; name: string;}`. Because `testData[0]` can be either of the two, you need to narrow it down to use safely.

Or you can

```
const testData = [
  { properties: { number: 1, name: 'haha' } , second: 'this type'},
  ['one', 'two', 'three'],
] as const;
```