# Typescript accessing array of number | number[] gives error

Tags: typescript

When I try to access array that has type of either number[] | number with index I  get error for subarray eventhough I check if element is of array type. To make things more confuse when I store reference to subarray in to variable it works without errors?

```
const minuteRange = [1, 2, 3, 4, [7, 9], [11, 13]];

const minRange = minuteRange;
// const lastEl: number[] | number =  minRange[minRange.length - 1] ?? 0;

// IF I REPLACE minRange[minRange.length - 1] ( last element in that array with lastEL up it works without error) 
const lastMinuteRangeNum = Array.isArray(minRange[minRange.length - 1])
    ? minRange[minRange.length - 1][1]
    : minRange[minRange.length - 1] ?? 0;
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFAIGMHsDsGcAu4C2BLWBXRBTASgIawDmO4AvOANoCMANAEx0DMdALHdQOx0CcAup1r1wNZv34BuCBBgJk6WIRJkKqDNnxFSk8BAD0%20qHCTgANgSQBRMwC5wWFACMcAJyr9wAHweZnbtXUlbRwqRWVSADozHBJEAAtwAFpRTwB%20NPAABmkwPNACkENwAEkAMVLwPCsABQAZAEEAYSsgiNDwkOjY4gTk1PAACnNLZBwYlFjkDHAEgmQCV1cCAE9wAHc0PotrOvBMAAdwLY3oVwBreA2t%20OhscDdXM4BKPRBjeRGkAFkNXHaAHJ%20NQNJarSJoeCg5YrQadFRhDDtbpxRIpGj8V4QcA43F4-EEwmEzLw0iI4IqFG9NGpWiebFExlMwn2UkdJFdGKo-oY8AZbK5QqgIA)

Comment: Are you trying to use a tuple? Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74309884/18244921) answer will give you some ideas. Otherwise, you have to narrow the expression before trying to index into it.

Comment: If you want the compiler to keep track of exactly which types are at which elements, you cannot annotate as a wide type like `D`, and you cannot just let the compiler infer the type using its default algorithm since you also get a too-wide type. You could instead use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to ask the compiler to prefer more specific types, like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WY36zN) shows. Does that work for you or am I missing something? (Please mention @jcalz to notify me if you reply.)

Comment: Oh, wait, you do say "dynamic" a few times.  So does that mean you *don't* want the compiler to keep track of the particular values?  Then you have to do an actual test like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WvGn4w) (which is what caTS said).  How would you like to proceed here?

Comment: Actually this question is no good as I was trying to simplify question from this link:  https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFAIGMHsDsGcAu4C2BLWBXRBTASgIawDmO4AvOANoCMANAEx0DMdALHdQOx0CcAup1r1wNZv34BuCBBgJk6WIRJkKqDNnxFSk8BAD0+qHCTgANgSQBRMwC5wWFACMcAJyr9wAHweZnbtXUlbRwqRWVSADozHBJEAAtwAFpRTwB+NPAABmkwPNACkENwAEkAMVLwPCsABQAZAEEAYSsgiNDwkOjY4gTk1PAACnNLZBwYlFjkDHAEgmQCV1cCAE9wAHc0PotrOvBMAAdwLY3oVwBreA2t+OhscDdXM4BKPRBjeRGkAFkNXHaAHJ+NQNJarSJoeCg5YrQadFRhDDtbpxRIpGj8V4QcA43F4-EEwmEzLw0iI4IqFG9NGpWiebFExlMwn2UkdJFdGKo-oY8AZbK5QqgIA

Comment: There is subtle difference in how I access nested array that makes error

Comment: I didn't mention this before, but a playground link by itself is not sufficient to be a code example in a post.  You need the plain text also.  The link is a nice supplement, but we can't *require* that people leave Stack Overflow to read the post.

Comment: Okay, you've run into [ms/TS#10530](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530). The type of `minRange.length - 1` is `number`, which is too wide for the compiler to perform control flow narrowing.  See the answers to the linked questions.  The workaround is, as you've already noticed, to save the problematic index result into a separate variable and check that.

Comment: Thnx jcalz, you have answered my question, I was going mad for not being able to figure it out...

Answer (score 0):

If your const array is defined by yourself, I would advise to use the `as const` syntax which is going to automatically create a dedicated type matching exactly your const array :

```
const t = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5]] as const;
// no problem here, because typeof t is: readonly [1, 2, 3, readonly [4, 5]]
console.log(t[3][0]);
```

More on this on the [literal inference section in the TS Reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-inference)

If your array is "dynamic" (created outside of your code), then I'd suggest to use `Array.isArray()` utility function, which is a type predicate and allows to seggregate the type of your array value at index 3 (given your type definition, it could either be a `number` *or* a `[number,number]`)

Something like:

```
type D = Array<number | [number, number]>
const t: D = [1,2,3, [4,5]]; 

if(Array.isArray(t[3])) {
  // here, typeguard allows to consider that t[3] can't be of type number => by deduction, it will necessarily be of type [number,number]
  console.log(t[3][0]);
  // Note that t[3][1] will be ok too, and t[3][2] will produce an error, which is (I think) what you're expecting
}
```

More on [Type Predicates in the TS Reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)